# Display and join table using column with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, null

I have into col1 value as below:

[image]

If I'm doing select:

```
select col1 from table1
```

How to instead of NULL display **X**?

It's possible then to join other table using values from col1? (A, B and X)

like: table1.col1 = table2.col1 ??

Comment: `select COALESCE(col1,'X') AS col1 from table1`

Comment: Also IsNull(Col1, 'RepalceValue')
dang enter key

COALESCE allows for multiple replace values such as COALESCE(Col1, Col2, 'ANother') checks if each is null down the chain

Comment: This kinda feels a lot like a homework question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Select x.Col1 
FROM Table1 x INNER JOIN Table2 y
ON (x.Col1 = y.Col1 or x.Col1 is NULL and y.Col1 is NULL)
```

Comment: @ Prabhat -> check on one view/tables and it's ok, I need to do more test :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL(col1,'X'), this will return the value of col1 if it is not null , else it will return the default value 'X'

```
select ISNULL(col1,'X') from table1
```

Comment: what about join there? can I do it something like: t1.ISNULL(col1,'X')=t2.ISNULL(col1,'X')  ??? on join statment?

Comment: Yes You could use the same ISNULL(col1,'X') on Joins

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.Col1 
FROM table1 x 
INNER JOIN table2 y on ISNULL(x.Col1, 'X') = ISNULL(y.Col1, 'X')
```